# Axis2 webservice using maven on weblogic 12c

Tags: java, web-services, maven, weblogic12c

I am trying to expose a webservice on weblogic and I have created .aar file using aar maven plugin and trying to include that service in axis2 admin page...I see the below screen saying that it is deployed(as shown in the below image), but not able to see that in the available services.

```
Upload an Axis Service Archive File

You can upload a packaged Axis2 service from this page in two small steps.

Browse to the location and select the axis service archive file you wish to upload
Click "Upload" button
Simple as that!

File AIMService.aar successfully uploaded 

Service archive :   

Hot deployment of new service archives is enabled

Hot update of existing service archives is disabled
```

I am tried to do the hot deployment too by placing the .aar file into the meta-inf folder, I am still not able to see the service. Even I didn't see the errors too..

Please help me. Dont get confuse with the wsdl to java plugin, I am actually consuming a .net webservice and republishing it by removing some tags.

I am attaching pom.xml below for your reference

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <axis2.version>1.5</axis2.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.16</log4j.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin.version>3.3</maven.compiler.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <finalName>XXXService</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-wsdl2code-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${axis2.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2code</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <wsdlFile>src/main/resources/pupdates.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                            <databindingName>xmlbeans</databindingName>
                            <packageName>com.XXXService</packageName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-java2wsdl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${axis2.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2wsdl</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <className>com.XXXclient</className>
                    <outputFileName>${project.build.directory}/XXXService.wsdl</outputFileName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Maven axis2 AAR plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
                <artifactId>axis2-aar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${axis2.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <servicesXmlFile>
                        src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/services/XXXService/META-INF/services.xml</servicesXmlFile>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>aar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/axis2/wsdl2code/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>target/generated-sources/xmlbeans/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>xmlParserAPIs</artifactId>
                    <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-adb</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-http</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-transport-local</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis2-xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>${axis2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: The .aar file should be placed into WEB-INF, not META-INF. See a discussion like: http://www.coderanch.com/t/424221/BEA-Weblogic/Unable-deploy-aar-files-weblogic for more info

Comment: Same .aar file when I deployed in Axis2 as a Standalone Server using the Standard Binary Distribution, it is working as expected. Do we need to follow any specific plugins for weblogic for code2wsdl?